# .height() is returning 0 value if the div has no content (only CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `div` with a background image. The div itself contains nothing except this code:

`<div class="container" style="background-image: url(URL);"></div>`

and the CSS code:

```
.container {

    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: local;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 50%;

}
```

When trying to detect the height with:

`var container_height = $('.container').height();`

it returns `0` even though in reality it's approximately `200px` in height.

I am assuming this is because the container has no content, only a background image with top padding. How do I fix it so I an get the actual height?

Comment: give us ur div code plz

Comment: It's there.. second line.

Comment: Sorry to everyone who felt the need to downvote. I searched for hours everywhere without finding a solution before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var container_height =  $('.container').outerHeight();
```

Consider using **outerHeight()** instead :)